# Listener method is calling twice while running the suits with testng.xml

Tags: selenium, logging, log4j, testng

I have prepared a `Listener` class to check the status of the method in the End if that is passed or failed. It's working fine, but it's being called twice after the execution of Method.

I have detailed my `Listener` class, `TestCase` class and 
output I'm getting below.

---

`Listener` Class:

```
    package com.qtpselenium.Listener;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
    import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
    import org.testng.ITestResult;
    import org.testng.Reporter;
    import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
    import org.testng.internal.Utils;

    public class CustomerListner extends TestListenerAdapter implements IInvokedMethodListener{
        // Listener class must be part of testng.xml
        Logger app_logs = Logger.getLogger("DEBUG");

        public void  onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {

            app_logs.debug(tr.getName() + " :  test case has been Failed ");
            System.out.println( tr.getName() + " :  test case has been Failed ");
        }

        public void  onTestSkipped(ITestResult tr) {

            app_logs.debug(tr.getName() + " :  test case has been Skipped ");
            System.out.println(tr.getName() + " :  test case has been Skipped ");
        }

        public void  onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {

            app_logs.debug(result.getName() + " :  test case has been Passed ");
            System.out.println(result.getName() + " :  test case has been Passed ");
        }

        public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult result) {
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
            System.out.println("*************TestsListenerAdapter******************");

            if (method.isTestMethod()) {
                List<Throwable> verificationFailures = ErrorUtil.getVerificationFailures();
                //if there are verification failures...
                if (verificationFailures.size() != 0) {
                    //set the test to failed
                    result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);

                    //if there is an assertion failure add it to verificationFailures
                    if (result.getThrowable() != null) {
                        verificationFailures.add(result.getThrowable());
                    }

                    int size = verificationFailures.size();
                    //if there's only one failure just set that
                    if (size == 1) {
                        result.setThrowable(verificationFailures.get(0));
                    } else {
                        //create a failure message with all failures and stack traces (except last failure)
                        StringBuffer failureMessage = new StringBuffer("Multiple failures (").append(size).append("):nn");
                        for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
                            failureMessage.append("Failure ").append(i+1).append(" of ").append(size).append(":n");
                            Throwable t = verificationFailures.get(i);
                            String fullStackTrace = Utils.stackTrace(t, false)[1];
                            failureMessage.append(fullStackTrace).append("nn");
                        }

                        //final failure
                        Throwable last = verificationFailures.get(size-1);
                        failureMessage.append("Failure ").append(size).append(" of ").append(size).append(":n");
                        failureMessage.append(last.toString());

                        //set merged throwable
                        Throwable merged = new Throwable(failureMessage.toString());
                        merged.setStackTrace(last.getStackTrace());

                        result.setThrowable(merged);

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod arg0, ITestResult arg1) {}


    }

***********************
`TestCase` class:

    package com.qtpselenium.suiteA;


    import org.testng.SkipException;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import com.qtpselenium.util.TestUtil;

    public class TestCaseA1 extends TestSuiteBase{

          String runmode[] = null;
          int count=-1;


        //Checking runMode of the Test case in Suite
        @BeforeTest
        public void checkTestcaseskip(){ 




            //this.getclass().getSimpleName() method returns the name of the class
            App_Logs.debug("checking run mode of " +this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " testcase");
            if(!TestUtil.IsTestCaseRunnable(suiteAxlsx, this.getClass().getSimpleName())){
                App_Logs.debug("Run mode of testcase " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is N");
                throw new SkipException("Run mode of testcase " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is N");

            }else

            App_Logs.debug("Run mode of testcase " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is Y");
                 runmode =  TestUtil.getDataSetRunmode(suiteAxlsx, this.getClass().getSimpleName());

        }



        @Test(dataProvider="getTestData")
         //No of arguments passed should be equal to no of dataelement in Testcase1 and type should be matched
        public void TestcaseA1(
                              String col1,
                              String col2,
                              String col3,
                              String col4

                              ){

            count++;
            if(runmode[count].equalsIgnoreCase("N")){

                throw new SkipException("The runmode for Testdata is N for row number " + count );
            }else{
            App_Logs.debug("Test data of testcase : " +  this.getClass().getSimpleName());
            App_Logs.debug(col1+"--"+col2+"--"+col3+"--"+col4);

            }
        }
     //Data provide to TestcaseA1
        @DataProvider
        public Object[][] getTestData(){


            return TestUtil.getdata(suiteAxlsx, this.getClass().getSimpleName());


        }
    }

*****************Testng.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestNG Dadadriver suite" allow-return-values="true" > 
<!-- suite name="Suite Name" AND Please remember all the tag names should be lowered case otherwise the sytem will throw an error --> 


          <listeners>
              <!-- packagename.customerlistner_classname  -->
                       <listener class-name="com.qtpselenium.Listener.CustomListner"/>
          </listeners>

        <suite-files>
               <suite-file path="./suiteA.xml" />
               <suite-file path="./suiteB.xml" />
               <suite-file path="./suiteC.xml" />

        </suite-files>




</suite>


*******************
output:

    uite read from excel suiteA  Suite passed by calling method  suiteA
    Run mode is NforsuiteA  Test case

    *************TestsListenerAdapter******************
    Data is Returned for Test caseTestCaseA1
    *************TestsListenerAdapter******************
    TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Skipped 
    TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Skipped 
    *************TestsListenerAdapter******************
    TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Skipped 
    TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Skipped 
    *************TestsListenerAdapter******************
    TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Skipped 
    TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Skipped 
    *************TestsListenerAdapter******************
    TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Skipped 
    TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Skipped 


I have 4 data set but it's writing 8 times that test case has been skipped.
```

Comment: Did you debug your example with a breakpoint in "onTestSkipped"?

Comment: I tried but Not getting why it's being invoked twice for each data set.

Comment: Hi , In my Logs i checked after the Testcase is over , it's invoking the Listener class is twice.                                                                                                                                23/01/2017 11:39:42 DEBUG Dummy Data_A1_1--Dummy Data_A1_2--Dummy Data_A1_3--Dummy Data_A1_4
23/01/2017 11:39:42 DEBUG TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Passed 
23/01/2017 11:39:42 DEBUG TestcaseA1 :  test case has been Passed

Comment: Which TestNG version do you use? Could you retry with the latest one?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with testng newest version 6.8, by changing the dependency version in pom.xml to 6.10 solved the problem.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have faced the same issue but I found the solution like below-
Add the @Listeners annotation on class level (where your @Test are located)
**e.g.**

```
@Listeners(listeners.ReportListener.class)
public class Test1 
{
    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        System.out.println("in Test1 method");
    } 
}
```

but do not include **listeners** tag in testNg.xml under the suite tag. remove from testng.xml 
Add @listeners annotation only on test class only. It will work.